# WordPress adding scaled images that don't exist (1536x1536 and 2048x2048)

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, block-editor

I'm building a theme in _S and using native Gutenberg blocks.

I have the following code via my functions.php file to set my image sizes:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'carousel', 1366, 550, true );
add_image_size( 'hero', 1366, 400, true );
add_image_size( 'large-square', 392, 340, true ); 
add_image_size( 'medium-square', 279, 314, true );
add_image_size( 'small-square', 215, 170, true );
add_image_size( 'diagram', 650 ); 
add_image_size( 'full-width', 884 ); 
add_image_size( 'half', 430 ); 
add_image_size( 'third', 279 ); 
add_image_size( 'quarter', 203 );
```

I also have this code to remove the default image sizes:

```
function remove_default_image_sizes( $sizes) {
    unset( $sizes['thumbnail']);
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['medium_large']);
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'remove_default_image_sizes');
```

When adding new images or regenerating my thumbnails via WP CLI, there are a number of generated image sizes that appear and do not recognise:

```
image-scaled-2048x600.jpg
image-scaled-1536x450.jpg
image-scaled-1024x300.jpg
```

I initially thought it could be down to the [recent WordPress 5.3 update](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/09/introducing-handling-of-big-images-in-wordpress-5-3/) that introduced a new way to manage large images.

I tried adding this to functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );
```

But I still get larger images that are scaled, like so:

```
image-scaled-2048x600.jpg
```

Where could WordPress be getting these image sizes from? I'm running a single plugin for the build ([ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the culprit!

WordPress 5.3 introduced additional image sizes which can be found via `/wp-includes/media.php`.

Updating my function, like so, removed the extra sizes:

```
function remove_default_image_sizes( $sizes) {
    unset( $sizes['large']); // Added to remove 1024
    unset( $sizes['thumbnail']);
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['medium_large']);
    unset( $sizes['1536x1536']);
    unset( $sizes['2048x2048']);
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'remove_default_image_sizes');
```

Answer (score 7):

You could also remove those image sizes completely using `remove_image_size` (see: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_image_size/)

Example (to be placed in your functions.php file):

```
remove_image_size('1536x1536');
remove_image_size('2048x2048');
```

This function, however, won't work for default WP image sizes (e.g. 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large', etc.). There's a work-around though. Simply set the sizes to 0:

```
update_option( 'thumbnail_size_h', 0 );
update_option( 'thumbnail_size_w', 0 );
update_option( 'medium_size_h', 0 );
update_option( 'medium_size_w', 0 );
update_option( 'medium_large_size_w', 0 );
update_option( 'medium_large_size_h', 0 );
update_option( 'large_size_h', 0 );
update_option( 'large_size_w', 0 );
```

Comment: Curious to know if this is actually a viable solution

Answer (score 0):

This is an update that works with Wordpress 6.x

2 functions:

```
// Remove certain image sizes or...
function remove_some_image_sizes() {
    foreach ( get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $size ) {
        if ( in_array( $size, array( '1536x1536','2048x2048' ) ) ) {
            // Will remove '1536x1536','2048x2048'
            remove_image_size( $size );
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'remove_some_image_sizes');

// Remove all but not default
function remove_extra_image_sizes() {
    foreach ( get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $size ) {
        if ( !in_array( $size, array( 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'medium_large', 'large' ) ) ) {
             // Will remove all except 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'medium_large', 'large'
             remove_image_size( $size );
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'remove_extra_image_sizes');
```